# running cron job in laravel 5

Tags: php, cron, laravel-5

I have registered my command as `php artisan run:process` and it looks like

```
  class queuedTransaction extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'run:process';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Running the queued transaction.';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(){
       DB::table('transfers')->truncate();
    }

}
```

this is my `kernel.php`

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{

    protected $commands = [
        \App\Console\Commands\Inspire::class,
        \App\Console\Commands\queuedTransaction::class,

    ];


    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {


      $schedule->command('run:process')->everyMinute();

    }
}
```

Now I want to run `php artisan run:process` every minute and truncate `transfers` table, but the `cron` is not working now. Just to make sure, if the `command` itself is working or not , I put my `command` inside my `routes` and call it, its truncating the table meaning command is doing its work.

Answer (score 0):

In Kernel.php your command should be included in:

```
/**                                                                                                             
 * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
 protected $commands = [
     MyCommand::class
 ];
```

You can probably remove Inspire too :)

Comment: So what user is running the cronjob? Being unable to write to logs can block execution. So if Apache is running under www-data but your login user is running the cronjob, that could throw it. Check /var/log/syslog (if appropriate) to see if the cronjob is running okay or if if an error shows immediately after it.

Comment: I have added my command like `/usr/local/bin/php /home/smsnep5/public_html/projectname/artisan schedule:run schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` , but its not doing any good. But the support team says cron job is running

Comment: PS i have updated my question as well. please have a look :)